# Bluetooth is disabled and not recognized on my Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: bluetooth, 20.10

Ubuntu 20.10 version. Bluetooth is disabled and it is not turning on. Can someone help me to fix this problem?

[image: when I try to turn on Bluetooth it shows like this.]

I tried these command: `lspci -knn | grep Net  -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue`, but my Bluetooth is not turning on and that command result is showing like this:

[image: and that command result is showing like this.]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net  -A3; lsusb; dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command.

Comment: `sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`